# Manually close x11 connection in ssh

Tags: shell, x11, openssh

I have setup a xclip on each of my server, thanks to this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/305681/253251). Now I can successfully grab remote output to my clipboard.

```
echo "test_v" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Will copy `test_v` to my clipboard, I can paste it on my local desktop.

---

But I'm facing another problem— apparently ssh refuse to logout cleanly, I have to manually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to end the ssh connection, I believe my case is similar to this one → [OpenSSH client hangs on logout when forwarding X connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634697/openssh-client-hangs-on-logout-when-forwarding-x-connections). Below output seem to confirm my suspicions.

```
$ ~#
The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/4 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1)
  #1 x11 (t4 r3 i0/0 o0/0 e[closed]/0 fd 7/7/-1 sock 7 cc -1)
```

How to manually close that x11 connection ?